# Shortest code to increment number with wrap/limit

Tags: javascript

Over the years I've often written code that loops through numbers within a finite limit. And my code is almost always the same.

```
var X = -360
function () {
    X += 1.5;
    if (X > 360) X = -360;
} // this function loops somewhere...
```

Javascript has changed a lot since I started using it and I've seen a lot of interesting things done lately with minified code, and I'm wondering what the shortest way to accomplish this is now.

I came up with this, but I'm wondering if it can get better.

```
X = ((X+=1.5)>360?-360:X)
```

I'd almost put money down that there's a duplicate for this question, but I couldn't find it while searching.

*Edit: I will mention that I'm not looking for a solution that fits just the specific numbers above, but a more generalized solution that fits the following:

- Increment (or decrement) a variable by an arbitrary amount.
- Reset that variable to a predetermined "default" value when it reaches an upper (or lower) limit.
- Signed float and integer safe.

To give an example of one of my use cases, I have an animation moving an element around using `sin` and `cos` calculating from a degree variable that I want to rollover at 360.

```js
const RAD = n => n*Math.PI/180
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 200; canvas.height = 200;
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var degree = 0;
function animate() {
  if ((degree+=2) > 360) degree = 0;
  let cos = Math.cos(RAD(degree)) * 80;
  let sin = Math.sin(RAD(degree)) * 80;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(100 + cos, 100 + sin, 10, 10, 0, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Comment: is the increment in X is of fix amount or it can be anything i.e. always increase by 5 or it can be any number ? also can X be modified by any other operation ? or it is just a counter which increases by 5 always

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment til after modifying my answer, but I believe it would answer your question now.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use mod operator, considering you're using x as counter and it always increase by fix amount

```js
let x = 0
x = (x + 5) % 365

console.log(x)

x = 355
x = (x + 5) % 365

console.log(x)

x = (x + 5) % 365

console.log(x)
```

Comment: This only works if you have positive quantities. If the number is negative it will not work.

Comment: @alex sure, but i am considering OP is starting from 0, as after limit is reached he's setting it to 0 which i believe is starting value

Comment: Yeah, just mentioned it for completeness :)

Comment: This won't work correctly if the starting value of `x` is anything other than a multiple of 5.

Comment: @Nick yes for sure, since op mentioned it is trying to use as a counter and increase by fix amount, and after limit it is reseted to 0, so i can safely consider this is not gonna be anything else than multiple of 5

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I should have provided a better example. I have come up with a solution like this before, and specifically had to veer away because it can't handle negative numbers. My mistake.

Comment: Wouldn't `Math.abs()` let us use negatives?